# Which even-graded integral cohomology classes arise as Chern classes?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, complex-geometry, vector-bundles

Given a CW complex $X$, is there some way to determine which even-graded elements of its integral cohomology ring $H^\star(X, \mathbb Z)$ arise as Chern classes of a complex vector bundle $E \to X$? I am particularly interested in the case where $X$ is an infinite-dimensional CW complex whose skeleta are all complex manifolds (e.g., direct limits of flag varieties or complex tori) and the restriction of $E$ to each skeleton is a holomorphic vector bundle.

Comment: Of course, all classes in degree $2$ can be realized by line bundles, but that's the easy part.

Comment: There are some restrictions mod 2 coming from the Wu formula. For example, on mod 2 reductions we have $Sq^2 c_2 = c_1c_2 + c_3$ for a complex vector bundle, which gives you something about the underlying ring structure if a given $c_3$ is to be realized. E.g. $S^6$ or $S^2 \vee S^6$, or other similar examples, do not carry a complex vector bundle with odd $c_3$.